# Where are the uploaded pictures in the newsfeed saved?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, social, newsfeed

When we upload a picture in the newsfeed (through the upload picture button) where does this picture go and where it is saved?

Because, after some time the feed expires and stops showing the old posts, so what's going on with the pictures then? Are they saved somewhere in some library or are they automatically deleted also?

Answer (score 1):

The Images in the newsfeed are stored in a list called "Microfeed", as attachments. You can see the links in the column "MediaLinkURI" (The MediaLinkType column will show a '1' in it for images).

This list is only available on Sites that have the Site Feature called "Site Feed" activated on it.

[image: Finding the Newsfeed Images]

Answer (score 0):

They are added to either the Site Assets library or the Photo library by default unless users choose to upload them elsewhere.

Comment: Ok but still i cant find the pictures, i just created a new team site without adding any libraries or lists to it and i added a picture into the newsfeed. Now where is this picture?

Comment: @user3437668 It depends how you add it. OOTB you can upload it to either Site Assets, Documents, or Form templates. But if you add it as a link (From Address), then it is not saved directly in you SharePoint.

Comment: Have you checked the picture url and find out where it is located?

Comment: This answer is incorrect.